# Stripe rails design choice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, stripe-payments

Scenario: I have a `User` that has the option to subscribe to a plan (SaaS) to create a number of `Posts` but also has the option to make a one time payment to create a `Post` without subscribing.

I have trouble understanding how many controllers/models I need and if I should associate them to the post or to the user. Of course a `Post` belongs to a `User`.

Should I have a payments model and controller for single payments and a subscriptions controller/model? or is it more logical to have one  Payment controller/model with a field :subscription for when the User chooses the subscription model?

Also, do I even need a model for payments since they are stored in stripe?

My credit card form would be the same for subscriptions and single payments so which model should I associate it with? or should I do a model-less form?

Thank you for any clarifications on the design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a question of stripe - it's about your system's structure

**Rails**

Although your payments details are stored in Stripe, you need to record & track them in Rails. This is especially true if you're handling payment plans, etc -- you need to be able to track whether someone's actually paid or not

This can only be done with Rails (I.E storing the time someone paid, etc)

---

**Code**

I'd do it like this (verrrrry basic):

```
#app/models/payment.rb
Class Payment < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
end

#app/models/user.rb
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :payment_plan
    has_many :payments
end

#app/models/payment_plan.rb
Class PaymentPlan < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :users
end

#app/controllers/payments_controller.rb
def new
   #Order Page
end

def create
   #Payment process / page
end
```

Schemas

```
users
id | payment_plan_id | created_at | updated_at

payments
id | user_id | created_at | updated_at

payment_plans
id | name | frequency | etc
```

Comment: This clarifies quite a lot thank you. In your opinion, should the payment_controller also handle payment_plan ordering? or should I also add a payment_plan_controller?

Comment: I'd add the payment_plan stuff to the users_controller (have other methods for assigning payment plans). It's best to keep it as modular as possible :)